# Excel Macros and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm extremely new to excel's VBA and to the idea of macros. My boss has asked me to try to figure out a way to figure out a solution to this problem:

"Each semester we are given an excel sheet with rows upon rows containing a students name, the class name (ACC, FIN, BIO...), course number (101 or 102...) and the section number 5162 (a unique identifier). Each semester teachers request the roster sheets for their classes. We typically have to create a new workbook with that professors name, then by hand copy and paste each row of one section of their class onto one sheet naming it accordingly ex BIO 102-5623, then the next section of that class into the next sheet and so on. We would like for you to figure out a way to automate this process so that we spend less time creating whole new workbooks and sheets and then copying and pasting all of the rows."

I figure that excel's VBA feature would be a good way to do this, but I've never used it before. I've done a lot of research on the tool since I started the project and have been watching a ton of tutorials, but I'm not sure if this will take several different macros to perform or if maybe this would be better to do in something like Access, or if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to do in Access.

The roster and classes already acts much like a database, and you have a unique identifier in that section number. Doing so with access or any kind of database would allow you to execute something like

```
select studentName from rosterDatabase where classId = 12345
```

and that would result in all the students in said class would populate the list.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this approach today and see how well it turns out.

Comment: Access worked great at first. But now my problem is that I can't get all of my fields to fit onto one sheet so when I try to out it into a report or PDF, it spreads out over multiple pages. I love that it let me select which criteria I wanted on the query, then before running it select to make a new table in a new database that I could name. If there was a way to do that in excel then that would be prefect